# How to view jmeter summary in stdout while running in nongui mode?

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to run a robustness test using jmeter through Jenkins and need to view the summary of the test in progress. When running the test locally using GUI mode, I can see the an agregate report of my test as it's running, is the same thing possible while I'm running in a nongui mode? I tried to change the summariser within properties file:

```
**#----------------------------------------------------------
# Summariser - Generate Summary Results - configuration (mainly applies to non-GUI mode)
#----------------------------------------------------------
# Define the following property to automatically start a summariser with that name
# (applies to non-GUI mode only)
summariser.name=summary
#
# interval between summaries (in seconds) default 3 minutes
summariser.interval=180
#
# Write messages to log file
summariser.log=true
#
# Write messages to System.out
summariser.out=true**
```

and also enabled logging information but I still don't see any summary. Even if I can get a constant logger within stdout then I can atleast view this within the console output from Jenkins, but currently I am not able to produce this. Does anyone know how to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

With JMeter 2.11, summariser is enabled by default in Non GUI mode, so you should have what you need.

Although what you show seems right except for :

> summariser.out=true**

Which should be:

> summariser.out=true

Answer (score 0):

Console status logger plugin can solve your task. See here:http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConsoleStatusLogger/